# Why not using root user as default

Tags: docker, security, containers, dockerfile

I've reading two topics about Docker security:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/

https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b

I understand for Docker image which are apps, the root user is not safe, so  the best option is creating a non-root user to run my service.

But what about development images? Docker images which are used when I need to build applications, not to run services?

Currently I'm using non-root user for development images, but I see few advantages when using it. For instance, when I want to use my Docker image in MS Azure, running as Container jobs, it requires a root user. Also, when I need to update my image, like installing a new package, I need to elevate that user, which has sudo permission.

Finally, is there a real recommendation for non-root user in Docker images, when an image is only for development and building?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outstanding introduction to what a container actually is: https://www.slideshare.net/jpetazzo/anatomy-of-a-container-namespaces-cgroups-some-filesystem-magic-linuxcon

*Containers are linux processes, running in the same kernel, separated by namespaces and limited by cgroups.*

The process inside a container has a user ID (UID) and a group ID (GID) associated with it: by default, the UID is 0 (which equates to root).

If the process inside the container is able to interact with resources outside the container (such as the underlying host's filesystem), then it will do so with the access rights associated with the UID/GID of that process.  So in the example where it runs as UID 0 (root), then that process can access & modify all the files on the underlying host, which is normally a bad thing.  (If you're using SELinux then it's not this simple, but let's not complicate things).

So if you can guarantee that your container process isn't going to touch the underlying host's filesystem and that it cannot be hijacked by an external system, then you're *probably* ok.  But what if your container process can be coerced into behaving strangely? Maybe this is a contrived example, but perhaps it reaches out to an external service which has been tampered with and which causes your process to crash or change its behaviour, such that it writes to the underlying host's filesystem or spawns a process that listens for connections from a remote system?

Additionally, are you the only person creating these container images?  Clearly you trust yourself, but if others are allowed to build similar containers, do you trust them? As in, really, really trust them?  Your containers may be fine, but what about theirs?  Can you guarantee that they won't (either maliciously, or by a mistake) allow their containers to access the underlying host's filesystem or resources?

Best practice is for your container to never run with UID 0.  There are few occasions where this is absolutely necessary and in enterprise environments it is a huge red flag for a container to be configured this way and very often your container will be prevented from running by the company's security systems.  If you must run the container process as UID 0, then consider using user namespace remapping (described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) and [here](https://success.docker.com/article/introduction-to-user-namespaces-in-docker-engine) and elsewhere), which is a way of the container running a process with UID 0 inside the container (so that the container process thinks it is root), outside the container, the process is given a very different (unprivileged) UID.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, very interesting. Yes, can guarantee that my container won't touch my filesystem, I won't use --volume, --port, -z (selinux). The possible flaw is the network, I gonna use "bridge", which allows external communication to upload any artifact. The image is used on CI jobs, but is public, in my case there is no problem, but maybe for some companies which are using. I agree with you UID 0 is not cool, but in my case I need because Azure Container jobs, which requires UID 0 to run an entrypoint.

Comment: If you're interested in container security, then Jessie Frazelle (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1250388/jessie-frazelle) knows a *lot* about it (well worth following on Twitter).

Comment: Thanks again, I'll follow her.

Answer (score 0):

One of dockers strengths is that your development env simulates exactly what will happen in prod

Let me give you a usecase / bug that I had

We are using nginx as our web server, I limited prod only images for root access, and on develop everything looked ok. After the release, I realised nginx has request buffer of 16k, when it exceeds it writes it to the disk (non-root user didn't had permissions to do so), and it returned error 500 to the client.

Everything looked ok on dev, until the point I got requests on prod larger than the 16K threshold.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "development images" I meant, images which contain a compiler to build an app, they won't run a recipe, it's just up/build/exit. The container won't touch my disk by a volume and the artifact will be uploaded. Your user case is when a container is running a service (nginx), which I totally agree running as non-root user. My case is more isolated, I see few problems, like user permission to read/run/write when building an app by the root user. I want to know if there are more real problems, like security flaw.